# Image is not displayed in overridden woocommerce email

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have overridden woocommerce *customer-completed-order.php*

```
<?php

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

do_action( 'woocommerce_email_header', $email_heading, $email ); 
?>

<p><?php printf( __( "Your recent order has been completed.<br> ,'woocommerce' ) ); ?></p>
```

How to add image to the end of the email?

I tried

```
<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( 1096 ,add_image_size('logo-size', 219,98) );  ?>
```

but only white space is displayed in the received email.

```
<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( 1096); ?>
```

displays it in a cropped size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`add_image_size()` isn't appropriate in the context it's being used in. The function is used to register a new image size so that when you upload an image, a cropped / scaled version is created matching the specified dimensions.

The code belongs in your `functions.php` file.

`wp_get_attachment_image()` is expecting you to pass in the name of the image size. Change your code to output the image in the email to:

```
<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( 1096, 'logo-size' ); ?>
```

Don't forget to regenerate (or re-upload) the image you'd like to use in the email. As the code was in the wrong place it wouldn't have applied to the image you've already uploaded.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/